# application role management in asp.net mvc (How)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have developed the asp.net mvc + C# application. it has 2 users as Super admin, Admin and User. I want to manage the functionality as per their roles. I am managing the data in sql server database .How to manage this in asp.net mvc ? where shuold i have to write the code for this management ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can think of two options.

You can use asp.Net's default `sqlMembershipProvider` and `sqlRoleProvider` to authenticate and authorize your users. If you do so you have to incorporate its database with yours. In this case you only have to write:

```
[Authorize(Role="Administrator")]
public ActionResult myAction(){}
```

The `authorize` attribute will only allow administrators to enter `myAction` actionresult. (Check to see if there is administrator role in asp.net membership and role database - there are almost half dozen roles there but I have not used them).

The second option is to use your own database for storing role information and writing your own authorize attributes and decorating your `actionresults` with them.
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488348) will help you understand how you can inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute` to write your custom authorization logic.