# ASP.NET: Own implementation of IsInRole

Tags: asp.net, authorization, roles

Is it possible to override the logic IsInRole in asp.net? I use my own tables of roles in the database and I would like to know how to use own logic.

Something like inheriting from PrincipialBase. Do you know some ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would only use RoleProvider if you are using other aspects of ASP.NET authentication and authorization management.  However, if you have your own database for storing role information and already have a UI for managing user roles, you can get away with just creating a GenericPrincipal with your roles and replacing HttpContext.Current.User with it during PostAuthenticateRequest (for ASP.NET).

MVC is slightly different, depending on how you are managing authorization.  Here is a related question.

[application role management in asp.net mvc (How)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896028/application-role-management-in-asp-net-mvc-how)

It is better to load all the roles for a user once per request then to check roles against the database multiple times during the request.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to implement a custom [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx). Here is a [guide to implement a RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released [the source code for the default providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx) (membership, role, etc...).
That is also a great reference when implementing your own provider. The one time I implemented a custom role provider, it served me very well.

Comment: Unfortunately links at the specified page are broken.

Comment: I just tried and they do work. Here is the download URL just in case http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi