# What do I return on my custom FilterAttribute if a user doesn't have the right authorization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, security, redirect, authorization

Here is my filter attribute:

```
public class RoleAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Roles { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            EfUsuarioRepository usuarioRepository = new EfUsuarioRepository();
            var loggedInUser = usuarioRepository.BuscarCuentaPorCorreo(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            string[] userRoles = usuarioRepository.GetRolesForUser(loggedInUser.UsuarioId);

            foreach (string definedRole in this.Roles.Split(','))
            {
                foreach (string role in userRoles)
                {
                    if (definedRole.Equals(role))
                        return;
                }
            }

            throw new SecurityException("Access not granted!");    
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SecurityException("Access not granted!");    
        }
    }
}
```

Now my question is what is the preferred way to redirect to an unauthorized page? Do I inject myself into the HttpContext and perform a redirect? What is a proven pattern for this? I just want an "Unauthorized" page as a catch all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute` you should inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3488348/291687) question has code that looks similar to what you're trying to do and the return type is a boolean of `true` or `false`.

Comment: Thanks, I've switched it out to use the AuthorizeAttribute. Another final bit, right now it's redirecting to Account/Logon regardless if I use `filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");`. Why?

Comment: Most likely it's set in your web.config. I'm pretty sure the value there overrides any filter context results that are set in the attribute.